# Need itemize list items without using a list

Tags: lists, indentation

For reasons too complicated to go into here, I need the ability to create something that looks like a list item without using a list. Specifically, I want each item to begin with a mark (which is a triangleleft, but that doesn't matter), and the text, if it wraps multiple lines, to wrap and indent just as a list item should. [Edit: I actually need these ersatz items to be standalone - that is, not inside any kind of enclosing structure like a table that requires an opening token and a closing token].

From reading other notes, I gather I can do this using a minipage to indent the text. Is there an easier way without loading additional packages? Thanks.

[Edit: it appears that there is some doubt that this is really what I need. The requirements are laid out in more detail [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52624/unexpanded-fails-with-undefined-latex-symbols). Bottom line: I have to put text inside another .tex file which, when processed, will create a tex file that I can process with a different set of macros to create my output. Thus the single tex file produces two PDFs eventually: the one generated by the file itself and the one generated by my generated tex file. The issue is that while I theoretically could use a list structure to hold the solutions that I'm writing, that requires a pretty complex set of boolean flags to put list ending code in the right place, and that is all pretty brittle. So I'd prefer a solution in which each solution stands alone.]

Comment: Could you illustrate how your input might look? I assume there is something that defines the limits of the list and the items.

Comment: The word `list` has a special meaning in LaTeX because it's the name of an environment. It is not clear why you cannot use a `list` environment. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: @josephwright No, there really isn't. I just want something that looks like a standalone list item but requires no enclosing structures. I can present the whole set of requirements if you want, but I think it will just confuse things.

Comment: Complicated or not, I wonder why you want to do this. Using `\begin{itemize}...\end{itemize}` adds structure to your document and makes it more readable.

Comment: Perhaps I should restate the requirements in a way that avoids using list terminology. I need to be able, at arbitrary points in my text, create a paragraph that is wholly indented by some amount, say 3em, and that has a mark at the left margin on the first line.

Comment: In response to the edit: there are several packages that allow you to write environments to external `tex` files for separate compilation. The `extract`  package is one such; `answer` is another. After extraction you can change the format in the preamble of the resulting `tex` source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be what you want,  with help from @ChristianR and from
[change the itemize from bullet to square](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64891/change-the-itemize-from-bullet-to-square)

```
 \documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{notalistitem}
{\begin{itemize}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\triangleright$} 
\item}
{\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}

Some text

\begin{notalistitem}
Here is text that should look like a list item although it doesn't
seem to be part of a list.
\end{notalistitem}

\begin{itemize}
\item This is part of a list.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** You'll need something more robust if you want to use an `itemize` inside this new environment, or one of these inside an `itemize`.

Comment: I ended up going with this answer because I do need the ability to have multiple paragraphs. I would have liked to mark @egreg's as accepted as well, though. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 7):

This won't work if `\xitem` is in a list environment, but only at the "outer level":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for the mock text

\newcommand{\xitem}{%
  \par\hangindent3em\hangafter0
  \noindent\llap{$\triangleright$\enspace}%
  \ignorespaces}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\xitem\lipsum[2]

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to have the symbol flush with the left margin, you can do

```
\newcommand{\xitem}{%
  \par\hangindent3em\hangafter1
  \noindent\makebox[3em][l]{$\triangleright$}%
  \ignorespaces}
```

Hanging indentation starts after one line, but the beginning of the first line is occupied by a box with the same width as the indent.

Comment: this looks like exactly what I want. Is there a way to push the item left so that the triangle is flush with the left margin?

Comment: @rogerl I've added the change you requested

Answer (score 6):

What about something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\def\myitem{\hangindent=5em$\triangleright$}

\myitem \lipsum[1]

\myitem \lipsum[2]

\myitem \lipsum[3]

\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

The advantage of using `\hangindent` is it has a single paragraph scope so there is no effect after the item that needs to be "ended". The drawback is that it falls over if your "items" are more than 1 paragraph long.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a table as follows (no packages required).

I've chosen `p{5cm}` for the second column to make the linebreak easier. This should give you an idea on how to tweak the table to get a result that you like.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lp{5cm}}
$\triangleright$ & some text \\
$\triangleright$ & a little bit more text, to provoke linebreak \\
$\triangleright$ & some text \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: I wasn't clear enough in my original post. I need to do this in a way that does not use an opening and closing bracket, line \begin{itemize}\end{itemize} or similarly for tabular.

Answer (score 1):

I won't go into whether there are better alternatives, but you can always use the TeX facilities built into the language for this kind of things, namely `\parshape`. Here's a simple macro that generates a paragraph with a hanging indent, using whatever symbol you want:

```
\def\ipar#1{\par\medskip
  \@tempdima=\textwidth \advance\@tempdima by -1.5em
  \parshape=2 0pt \textwidth 1.5em \@tempdima\relax
  \noindent\hbox to 1.5em {#1}}
```

You can use it like this (or define another macro to supply the triangle):

```
\ipar{$\bullet$\hfil} Here comes the paragraph text.
```

*Explanation*: `\parshape` is used with a number of pairs `(<indentation>, <line length>)`. The last pair is used for any remaining lines. The syntax is

```
\parshape <number-of-pairs> (pair 1) (pair 2) ...
```

With judicious choices you can build circular paragraphs, etc. The rest of the macro calculates the line length from the desired indentation (which is hard-coded to 1.5em).