# Use of \xappto, \noexpand and (for example) \emph

Tags: foreach, etoolbox

I'd like to accumulate some text from a macro and place it in a multipart Ti*k*Z node. Works as expected until there is a macro in the text being accumulated, at which point TeX fails. It would, as indicated, be possible to add `\noexpand` to the macro in the text, but as there may be a lot of text containing macros that would be less-than-optimal. I've looked at some of the pointers in comments in [\unexpanded fails with undefined LaTeX symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52624/unexpanded-fails-with-undefined-latex-symbols), but so far have found no workaround.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{m}{%
    \foreach \m [count=\sn from 1] in {#1}{%
        \xappto{\mtext}{\noexpand\nodepart{\numword{\sn}} \m}
    }%
}

\def\numword#1{%
    \ifcase#1 \or one\or two\or three\or four\or five\or six\or seven\or eight\or nine\or ten\or eleven\or twelve\or thirteen\or fourteen \or fifteen\or sixteen\or seventeen\or eightteen\or nineteen\or twenty\fi
}

%% |=====8><-----| %%

\parindent0pt

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw,rectangle split,rectangle split parts=20,rectangle split ignore empty parts]
        {\foo{1,2,3,4}\mtext}; %% <<-- no error
        %{\foo{\emph{1},2,3,4}\mtext}; %% <<-- error
        %{\foo{\noexpand\emph{1},2,3,4}\mtext}; <<-- no error
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\unexpanded\expandafter{\m}`

Comment: Gosh -- I thought I'd tried all of the combinations of `\unexpanded` `\noexpand` and `\expandafter` but, apparently, not that one. Thanks -- make that into an answer and I'll gladly accept...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each item in the list is stored in `\m`, so you need to expand `\m` once, but not more than once to avoid things like `\emph` exploding.  One hit with `\expandafter` will expand something once, and `\unexpanded` will prevent that thing from expanding, so if you combine both you get:

```latex
\unexpanded\expandafter{\m}
```

(the `\expandafter` skips over the brace and expands `\m`).  You don't need an `\expandafter` before `\unexpanded` because `\unexpanded` (as do `\toks<num>`, `\detokenize`, `\scantokens`, etc.) expands all tokens before the `{`.

Also, `etoolbox` provides a conveniently named `\expandonce` macro, that does exactly that:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{m}{%
    \foreach \m [count=\sn from 1] in {#1}{%
        \xappto{\mtext}{\noexpand\nodepart{\numword{\sn}} \expandonce{\m}}
    }%
}

\def\numword#1{%
    \ifcase#1 \or one\or two\or three\or four\or five\or six\or seven\or eight\or nine\or ten\or eleven\or twelve\or thirteen\or fourteen \or fifteen\or sixteen\or seventeen\or eightteen\or nineteen\or twenty\fi
}

%% |=====8><-----| %%

\parindent0pt

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw,rectangle split,rectangle split parts=20,rectangle split ignore empty parts]
        {\foo{\emph{1},2,3,4}\mtext}; %% <<-- error
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

The mandatory `expl3` version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #1 }
  \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \exp_not:N \nodepart{\numword{##1}}~\exp_not:n { ##2 } }
   }
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\numword[1]{%
  \ifcase#1 \or one\or two\or three\or four\or five\or six\or
  seven\or eight\or nine\or ten\or eleven\or twelve\or thirteen\or
  fourteen\or fifteen\or sixteen\or seventeen\or eightteen\or
  nineteen\or twenty\fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw,rectangle split,rectangle split parts=20,rectangle split ignore empty parts]
        {\foo{1,2,3,4}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw,rectangle split,rectangle split parts=20,rectangle split ignore empty parts]
        {\foo{\emph{1},2,3,4}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The list is transformed into a sequence and so we can use `\seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn` where in the loop code `#1` refers to the index and `#2` refers to the item. Since we're in a definition, they become `##1` and `##2`.

This populates a token list variable where we want just to expand `\numword`, that we can deliver at once.

A “cleaner” version without the need of suppressing expansion by using indirection.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{m}
 {
  \sgmoye_foo:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__sgmoye_foo_items_seq
\tl_new:N \l__sgmoye_foo_body_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \sgmoye_foo:n
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__sgmoye_foo_items_seq { #1 }
  \tl_clear:N \l__sgmoye_foo_body_tl
  \seq_map_indexed_function:NN \l__sgmoye_foo_items_seq \sgmoye_foo_add:nn
  \tl_use:N \l__sgmoye_foo_body_tl
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \sgmoye_foo_add:nn
 {
  \__sgmoye_foo_add:en { \numword{#1} } { #2 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__sgmoye_foo_add:nn
 {
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__sgmoye_foo_body_tl { \nodepart{#1} #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__sgmoye_foo_add:nn { e }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\numword[1]{%
  \ifcase#1 \or one\or two\or three\or four\or five\or six\or
  seven\or eight\or nine\or ten\or eleven\or twelve\or thirteen\or
  fourteen\or fifteen\or sixteen\or seventeen\or eightteen\or
  nineteen\or twenty\fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw,rectangle split,rectangle split parts=20,rectangle split ignore empty parts]
        {\foo{1,2,3,4}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw,rectangle split,rectangle split parts=20,rectangle split ignore empty parts]
        {\foo{\emph{1},2,3,4}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Food for thought. The first version I can follow without issue; the "cleaner" version will take some time...